# Calling method from another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewControllerA and a ViewControllerB. I want calling a method of ViewControllerA from ViewControllerB.

In ViewControllerA is present a method:

```
  -(NSMutableArray*) loadData;
```

In ViewControllerB.h:

```
 #import "ViewControllerA.h"
  .......
 @property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerA * viewControllerA;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * mutableArray;
```

In ViewControllerB.m:

```
self.mutableArray =[viewControllerA loadData];
```

but the method is not calling. Why? Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add the function to header of the viewcontroller?

Comment: Did you mean for the method in viewControllerA to be a class method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing

```
self.
```

As long as somewhere in viewControllerB:

```
self.viewControllerA = [[viewControllerA alloc]init];  //or some other initialization occurs...
```

then:

```
self.mutableArray =[self.viewControllerA loadData];
```

will work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the method loadData is specified in viewControllerB's header file.

```
- (void)loadData;
```

After than, you can now call the method loadData.

```
[viewControllerA loadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

viewControllerA is allocated in ViewControllerB before calling [viewControllerA loadData]?

Answer (score 0):

While pushing controller B from controller A..just specify

```
viewControllerB.viewControllerA = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

and then from B call the method A.The problem which you faced is due to non allocation and just declaratio of "viewControllerA " which you had created in B.