# iOS Perform method in another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, methods

I have a `FethViewController` and a `DisplayViewController`...

`FethViewController` has a method in it that fetches JSON from a webservice.

I want to access that JSON object or rather perform the fetch method in `DisplayViewController`.

How do I do this? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855931/calling-method-from-another-viewcontroller) but it didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Are any of these controllers your root view controller? What is the relationship between them, and the app delegate?

Comment: neither are rootview controllers. the displayviewcontroller is the second view in a tabbar interface. the fethviewcontroller is for the view that preceeds the tabbar interfae. i.e. you go through the feth view to goto the tabbar interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without understanding the broader context of your application architecture, I'd say you have two options:

1. **Dependency injection** - Since you fetch JSON in the context of a view that precedes a distal view that also needs the JSON, then one option is to pass the JSON object along the hierarchy - i.e. to your `UITabBarController` etc.  I believe that the link you posted in the question refers to dependency injection.   When you say *"it didn't work"*, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that.
2. Make the JSON object a property of a **singleton class** - Perhaps you could create a singleton class that manages network access.  Then objects that have obtuse relationships in your object graph could access the network and the results of network calls without the messiness of dependency injection.

Finally, I'm not asserting that either of these is better than the other (or better than other alternatives) because we understand little of your application's goals and remaining architecture.

Comment: +1 for the first option. Using a Singleton for this is FUGLY (IMHO).

Comment: Agree (usually) - hard to say in this case without more detail.